# Merging selected features in one DBF table (polygons) using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, python-2.7

I'm absolutely new to Python and programming. How can I merge selected features in one DBF table (polygons) using Python in ArcGIS 10.2 for Desktop?

Here's what I need:

[image]

Here's what I've got:

> > > arcpy.Dissolve_management(S2_merge1, S2_dissolve5, "Name5", "", MULTI_PART", "DISSOLVE_LINES")
> > >
> > > arcpy.JoinField_management(S2_dissolve5, "Name5", S2_merge1, "Name5", "Name1")

This works but I need to do this without dissolve command - You see I need to merge selected features in one shp/dbf like I do this in Editor session. I can't find this type of toolbox/command in ArcGIS

And is there any possibility to configure the Dissolve tool to get shp-theme with all fields what was in original shapefile like it was in ArcView 3.2?

Comment: In your example, when `Name5` has the value As3, your input table has three potential values for field `Name1`: A, B, and C. Your output table chose the value A. Is there a logic you'd like when there are multiple possible values?

Comment: I need two solutions - fist - i need simple merge with fist value ( A ) in row    and second objective is to merge values in these rows into one merged row - A+B+C

Answer (score 2):

Since you are new to python and arcpy, I will say that this problem is more complicated than the steps you usually do in ArcMap. However, if you have a large table or a large number of shapefiles, arcpy will save you lots of time.

The proper (IMO) way to do this is with the `.union` function for geometry objects and `arcpy.da.InsertCursor` for the attributes. Without an exact description it's hard to code exactly what you need, but I'll give it a shot.

Some helpful links:

[Alternative to 'Editors Merge' feature using Arcpy](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/194268/alternative-to-editors-merge-feature-using-arcpy)

http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/create-feature-class.htm

[Possible to add multiple fields in single arcpy statement?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/57380/possible-to-add-multiple-fields-in-single-arcpy-statement)

```
# First, create an output feature class with the desired schema
arcpy.CreateFeatureClass_management(r'C:\Path\To\Output', 'output.shp', 'POLYGON', spatial_reference='S2_merge1')

fields = [
('NAME5', 'TEXT'),
('NAME1', 'TEXT'),
# ... Add fields as necessary]

for field in fields:
    arcpy.AddField_management(*(r'C:\Path\To\Output\output.shp',) + field)

# Now that we have the output dataset, we will populate it in 2 steps
# Step 1: Merge all the geometries for shapes that have the same Name5 value
# Step 2: For each set of merged geometries, populate the Name1
# attribute with the unique letters of all the Name1 attributes for that set.
# In your example, As3 would have 'ABC'

# Get unique values for the column you want to 'dissolve' on
unique_names = sorted({r[0] for r in arcpy.da.SearchCursor('S2_merge1', 'Name5')})
# This will give you a list like ['As1', 'As2', 'As3']

# Next you need to merge the geometries that share the same Name5 
with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(r'C:\Path\To\Output\output.shp', ['SHAPE@', 'Name1', 'Name5']) as icur:
    for name5 in unique_names:
        query = "Name5 = '{}'".format(name5) # For example Name5 = 'As1'
        geoms_to_merge =  [r[0] for r in arcpy.da.SearchCursor('S2_merge1', 'SHAPE@', query) ]
        merged_names = sorted({r[0] for r in arcpy.da.SearchCursor('S2_merge1', 'Name1', query) })
        parent_geom = geoms_to_merge[0]
        if len(geoms_to_merge) > 1:
            child_geoms = geoms_to_merge[1:]
            for geom in child_geoms:
                # Union each child geometry with the parent
                parent_geom = parent_geom.union(geom)
        name1 = ''.join([i for i in merged_names])
        insert_row = (parent_geom, name1, name5)
        icur.insertRow(insert_row)

# This should give you an ouput table that has rows equal to the number of unique values in the Name5 column.
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and was able to solve it using the [previous answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/218200/115), however, there are some small things that i had to correct from [the code KJYDavis provided](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/218200/115).

The first is only a typo:

unqiue_names instead of unique_names

```
### Get unique values for the column you want to 'dissolve' on
unique_names = sorted({r[0] for r in arcpy.da.SearchCursor('S2_merge1', 'Name5')})
```

The second is in the query:

```
query = "Name5 = {}".format(name5) #did not work for me

query = "  'Name5'  =  '{}'   ".format(name5) # worked
```

The third is in the last line:

```
icur.insertRow(row) # did not work

icur.insertRow(insert_row) # worked
```